# Can Android Studio be setup as an environment for malware analysis?

Tags: android-studio, android-emulator, analysis, malware, malware-detection

As the topic suggests, how exactly can we use android emulators like Android studio to create a sandbox-like environment(or can we?) (in this context: detection of malicious files). I've heard of REMNUX distro for malware analysis, but dk how to get started with in the very first. Any suggestions are appreciated

Emulators for malware analysis in android devices

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I have no idea about android emulators, but you can use Remnux for static/code analysis of android malwares. Also,Remnux has a rich documentation and you can download the remnux image(VM or Docker) and run it easily. More information is available at : https://remnux.org/?ltclid=